# Git discard changes in working directory submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am working in a submodule and am having trouble untracking a folder full of files

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
    #   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/office2003/fck_dialog.css
    #   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/office2003/fck_editor.css
    #   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/silver/fck_dialog.css
    #   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/silver/fck_editor.css
    #   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckconfig.js
    #   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckeditor.js
    #   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckpackager.xml
```

I type

```
git reset --hard
```

which returns

> HEAD is now at b2c5a77 nothing

However when I type

```
git status
```

I am again greeted with the long list of files. I have tried to

```
git clean -f
```

and also removed the entire submodule and checked out from the master server. 
I have also tried to delete the entire project whom the submodule belongs to, pulled that and then initiated and updated the submodule but to no avail.

```
rm -rf project
git clone foo@bar.project.net:/home/rails/repo/gits/project.com
#Cloning into project...
#remote: Counting objects: 2452, done.
#remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2040/2040), done.
#remote: Total 2452 (delta 1238), reused 582 (delta 145)
#Receiving objects: 100% (2452/2452), 561.32 KiB | 438 KiB/s, done.
#Resolving deltas: 100% (1238/1238), done.
cd project.com
git submodule init
git submodule update
#Cloning into vendor/plugins/project_engine...
cd vendor/plugins/project_engine
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/office2003/fck_dialog.css
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/office2003/fck_editor.css
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/silver/fck_dialog.css
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/editor/skins/silver/fck_editor.css
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckconfig.js
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckeditor.js
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckpackager.xml
```

The only thing that seems to remove the files is if I log on as another use on my Mac, which makes me think its a problem my local machine and not the repo itself.

I have also tried to uninstall and reinstall GIT and am currently running 1.7.5.4 install and complied with the help of brew (Ruby package manger).

How do I remove these files from git status?

Comment: which files you want to remove?

Comment: I want to remove any files from being changes not staged for commit, I want to checkout the master branch, with the master submodule and am expecting to type git status and have nothing to commit but I cant seem to "shake" these files

Comment: What you say about `git status` still showing files as "changed but not updated" directly after a `git reset --hard` is very surprising.  Are you sure you didn't do the `git reset --hard` in the supermodule, but the `git status` in the submodule?  Do you have any clean or smudge filters set up?  Have you set `core.autocrlf`?

Comment: I am definitely performing the git reset --hard and the git status in the submodule, I double checked with a pwd which returns ~/Sites/project.com/vendor/plugins/arena_engine I have also set git config --global core.autocrlf true I tried false as well to see if it would fix it, im getting desperate

Comment: Are you able to change and save any of those files, just to see whether this might be some problem with permissions?  (Although if that were the problem I'd be surprised that there weren't error messages.  On the other hand, the `rm project` you quote would clearly be an error if it was a directory, so perhaps there's some other error output missing...)

Comment: The project is removed using rm -rf this was just a typo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with Richard that this *could* stem from a case sensitivity/insensitivity problem. I will address that issue with this answer.

**Problem**

If a git commit contains two files whose names differ only in case, checking out that commit to a working directory in a case-insensitive filesystem causes problems. If the commit contains, for example, `myfile` and `myFILE`, git will create `myfile`, and then when it goes to create/update `myFILE`, the filesystem gives it a handle to `myfile`.

This becomes apparent if myfile and myFILE have different contents in the repository. When checking out the files, the second one "wins" and the physical file contains the contents of the second file. When you do `git status`, the two files in the index both get compared to the same file in the working directory, and for the losing file, the contents don't match.

**Verifying the Problem**

You could checkout the repository on a case-sensitive system to analyze and resolve everything there. Alternatively, git does provide enough tools to deal with this on your current system.

The easy way to see if this is really the problem, is to make a trivial modification to one of files listed. Then, running `git status` should show both variants of the filename, since the working dir version does not match either version in the index:

```
$ echo >> public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckpackager.xml
$ git status
Possible outcome:
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   ...
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckpackager.xml
#   modified:   public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/FCKPACKAGER.xml
```

Or, you can also use `git ls-files` to see what's in the index:

```
$ git ls-files public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckpackager.xml
public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckpackager.xml
public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/FCKPACKAGER.xml
```

If you want to see exactly what is in each file, you can use `git checkout-index` to pull a file out of the index and save it somewhere (using a prefix so contents are written to separate files):

```
$ git checkout-index --prefix=v1/ public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/fckpackager.xml
$ git checkout-index --prefix=v2/ public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/FCKPACKAGER.xml
```

**Resolution**

Once you have figured out which variant of each file you want to remove, you can remove it from the index using `git rm --cached`, which respects the case of the paths given to it:

```
$ git rm --cached public/javascripts/app/fckeditor/FCKPACKAGER.xml
```

then commit, and if necessary do another `git reset --hard`

---

However, your comment about logging in as a different user and getting different result indicates there might be a different problem. That being the case I would see if there are any differences in the user-specific .gitconfig files.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue, there was a problem with .gitconfig removing the following has fixed the issue [apply]
 whitespace = fix

Answer (score 2):

For cleaning untracked file, you should use

`git clean -xdf`

instead of

`git clean -f` only

-d
           Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked
           directory is managed by a different git repository, it is not removed by
           default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.

-x
           Don’t use the ignore rules. This allows removing all untracked files,
           including build products. This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git
           reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.

Comment: I tried git clean -xdf however when I type git status the files are still there to be commited

Comment: `git clean` won't touch tracked files, so this is unrelated to the problem

Answer (score 2):

You might be experiencing a case sensitivity problem.  By default, Mac filesystems are case preserving but not case sensitive.

Git itself is case sensitive.  If you don't have a case sensitive filesystem and there are two files checked in whose names differ only by case, `git status` will show one of the files as modified (assuming the contents of the two files is different).  If you have two *directories* whose names differ only by case (e.g., `fckeditor` and `FCKeditor`), then Git may show lots of modified files.

Try creating a case-sensitive volume and run `git clone` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Change to the submodule directory - it is its own repo - before you do operations on that submodule repo. You should then be able to clean and fix the sub-module repo 'in the usual ways'.

The various sub-module articles (progit & git community book), while they do mention it, aren't as clear as needed to pick that point.

Comment: The OP deleted and re-cloned the entire project and the problem was still there, so something else is going on -- the "usual ways" won't work.